# How to do I associate two different objects with each other

Tags: java, oop

```
        Citizen c1 = new Citizen();
        Dose d1 = new Dose();   
        Dose d2 = new Dose();
```

Now I want to assign these two doses to this specific citizen and put them in a single list. So these objects are all related to each other in the list and are a same set of information.

Comment: One possibility would be if the `Citizen` knows its doses. So it could have a `List<Dose> doses` field and offer a method `addDose(Dose dose)` where it just `doses.add(dose)`.
Or a setter `setDoses(List<Dose> doses)` and you pass `List.of(d1, d2)` to it.

Comment: If there are only going to be two, always, then you can just declare two different fields to store those Dose references, along with appropriate getters/setters. If you'll hold an unknown number and need flexibility then use a List as suggested by Zabuzard.

Comment: I have to add like 7 citizens, some with no doses, some with one or two. So, I was wondering if there is a way to add a dose to a specific citizen because hard coding it would make no sense since I have to sort the list too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commentators are dead right, but I feel the short hints are not sufficient as an answer. Basically I am understanding two things in the question:

- You want to assign the doses to a specific citizen - that part was answered in the comments
- you want to put them all in one single list - we do not know whether that list should be doses, citizens or even a mix.

It all matters how you define your classes so you can navigate back and forth:

```
public class Dose {
    private Citizen citizen;

    public void setCitizen(Citizen citizen) {
        this.citizen = citizen;
    }

    public Citizen getCitizen() {
        return citizen;
    }
}

public class Citizen {
    private List<Dose> doses;

    public Citizen() {
        doses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addDose(Dose dose) {
        if (!doses.contains(dose)) {
            doses.add(dose);
            dose.setCitizen(this);
        }
    }

    public List<Dose> getDoses() {
        return new ArrayList<Dose>(doses);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Citizen c1 = new Citizen();
    Dose d1 = new Dose();   
    Dose d2 = new Dose();
    c1.addDose(d1);
    c1.addDose(d2);

    // let's see what doeses a citizen has
    System.out.println(c1.getDoses());
    // let's see where dose 1 ended up
    System.out.println(d1.getCitizen());

    // let's put them all in one list - that requires a common base class, and we currently have just 'Object'.
    List<Object> dosesAndCitizens = new ArrayList<>();
    dosesAndCitizens.add(c1);
    dosesAndCitizens.add(d1);
    dosesAndCitizens.add(d2);

    System.out.println(dosesAndCitizens);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from your description it looks you need list within Citizen objects , and you can provide `addDose(Dose dose)` function , even more you can add setter function `setDoses(List<Dose> doseList)` to set the list Dose in one step , example would be like :

```
public class Citizen {
...
...
List<Dose> doseList = new ArrayList<Dose>();
.
.
public void addDose(Dose dose){
doseList.add(dose);
}

public void setDoseList(List<Dose> doses){
doseList= doses;
}


}
```